# Receber apenas número em campo de dinheiro

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Estou buscando um `td` com jQuery.

`var linhaTr = $("tbody").find("tr:first-child");`

`var tamanhoTd = linhaTr.find("td:nth-child(2)").text();`

e ele me retorna por exemplo `R$ 5,00`. Mas eu preciso receber de volta para fazer cálculos o valor `5.00`. Tirar o R$ e mudar a virgula por ponto...

Além disso...

Gostaria de saber se é "Expressões Regulares" que preciso para poder capturar o texto de forma especial, obtendo apenas algumas coisas, preciso estudar isto e não sei o nome direito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se quiseres podes usar regex, nesse caso é para capturar a parte importante nessa string. Podia ser algo assim ([exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/sDPEIc/1)):

```
var parteNumerica = string.match(/[\d\.\,]+/);
```

Mas podes simplesmente partir a *string* e tirar a parte numérica como o [@Lucas Costa referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/174713/129). Nesse caso é ainda mais importante que a *string* tenha esse formato exatamente.

Nesse caso podes fazer assim:

```
var parteNumerica = string.split(' ').pop();
```

### Exemplos:

Com regex:

```js
var string = 'R$ 5.000,50';
var parteNumerica = string.match(/[\d\.\,]+/);
var numero = Number(parteNumerica ? parteNumerica[0].replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.') : 0);
console.log(numero);
```

Sem regex:

```js
var string = 'R$ 5.000.400,50';
var parteNumerica = string.split(' ').pop();
var numero = Number(parteNumerica ? parteNumerica.split('.').join('').replace(',', '.') : 0);
console.log(numero);
```

Comment: `pop` pode ser mais elegante do que acessar o índice nesse caso :p

Comment: Eu recomendaria usar regex também no replace do ponto, pois caso seja um número na casa dos milhões o replace não tira todas as ocorrências do ponto. Assim: parteNumerica.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'), teria certeza que todos as ocorrências de ponto no número seriam removidas

Comment: Não deu certo, o resultado é NaN

Comment: @BrunoCabral corrigi, tinha um bug. Se não der diz qual a _string_ que estás a usar.

Comment: @GabrielWeber bem visto! corrigi :)

Answer (score 4):

Se o resultado é *R$ 5,00* por exemplo, uma forma inicial pode ser:

```js
var recuperado = "R$ 5.500,10";
var numero = parseFloat(recuperado.split(" ")[1].replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
console.log(typeof numero, numero);
```

Onde é removido o sinal monetário, renomeado "," para "." e convertido para tipo numérico.